# Can we just import all the tag-wiki from other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tagging

I am seeing many tags like `c++`, `rss` etc which are common on the SE ecosystem. Is there a way to import these tags from any other SE website to Ethereum SE?

If yes, it would help us keep the tags meaningful with minimum effort.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is *no*.

Apart from the technical considerations, tag wiki *excerpts* were ***not*** meant to simply define what a word means. Excerpts should describe *when* and *how* that tag is to be used on this site specifically.

If a tag excerpt says something like *"C++ is a programming language created in the early '80s by… etc."*, you're probably missing the point of providing tag-usage guidance for this site.

Tag *wikis* are the larger, free-form component of the tagging ecosystem. It provides an opportunity to compile a resource about that subject for *this* community specifically. Again, if a tag wiki contains a lot of generic information of no particular interest to this community, you're probably not using tag wikis for the purpose they were intended.

Comment: A nice example of this are the respective C++ tags on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B) and on [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. However using in different sites and different context won't change the actual purpose and definition of most of the terms like  `c++` or `rss`. Difference i can see is, they mentioned it is for Aurdino on the arudino SE and general purpose in SO. Although i am not expecting to blindly import all the tags.